# Problemas para mostrar cor da fonte em campo ativo

Tags: css, html5, css3

boa noite!

Eu estou passando por um problema que está quebrando minha cabeça por dias. Eu tento deixar a cor da letra no campo ativo do tab, porém quando eu passo (color: #fff) para a classe especifica, ela não muda, porém ela reconhece o background passado na mesma classe. Tentei mudar varias classes, porém sem sucesso, como mostra a imagem.

Vocês poderiam me ajudar com alguma dica

Está é a página: https://www.colegiofreinet.com.br/duvidas-frequentes2/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Moises Fausto** eu irei responder a sua pergunta, porém antes eu gostaria de deixar bem claro algumas coisas para você.

O seu site **não está seguindo nenhuma convenção** de **boas práticas**, **code clean**, **design patterns**, **metodologias** entre outros, alguns problemas que eu analisei apenas inspecionando o código pelo browser foram o seguinte:

> 1) Na **tag** `<head>` você está inserindo `<script>` onde o local deles são **dentro** da **tag** `<body>` e no **final** de todas as **marcações de texto da tag**. **O Por que disto?** **Todo javascript executa de modo síncrono por padrão**, isso significa que quando a **tag** `<script>` é encontrada, o **browser não renderiza mais nada enquanto este script não for carregado e executado**.
>
> Inserir um `<script>` no `<head>` **garante** que ele seja executado **antes de qualquer elemento inserido** na **tag** `<body>`, a **desvantagem** é que o **usuário só irá visualizar uma página em branco até que o script termine de executar**. Logo, **inserir** um `<script>` no **final** do `<body>`, por outro lado, permite que o **conteúdo** **antes dele já** **seja exibido ao usuário**, **sem ter de esperar cada mínimo detalhe estar pronto antes de ler o conteúdo da página**, a **desvantagem** é que se o seu `<script>` modifica significativamente o conteúdo e/ou sua apresentação e funcionalidade o usuário irá visualizar uma **página mal formatada** **antes que o script altere-a**.
>
> 2) Segue o mesmo padrão de resposta para a **tag** `<style>` dentro da **tag** `<head>`. Quando você faz isto o seu `<style>` é denominado de **"CSS Interno"**, as `.class` e `#id` que são utilizadas para se referir a **um ou muitos elementos**, neste caso **só poderão ser ativos nesta página específica**, porém o p**roblema não é somente este**. Desta forma que esta todo o código dentro de `<style>` será **baixado cada vez que a página for carregada**, a **desvantagem** é que isto **aumenta o tempo de carregamento da página e afeta apenas uma página com os estilos, sem poder reutiliza-los**.
>
> O **correto seria não utilizar** o **"CSS Interno"** e nem o **"CSS Inline"**, **somente o "CSS Externo"**. Com o **"CSS Externo"** você tem a **vantagem** de uma **estruturação mais limpa e reutilização do código, velocidade de carregamento mais rápido** entre outros.

Existem diversos outros problemas, mas estudando e praticando é que você irá lapidar suas habilidades, existem diversos assuntos a serem estudados, porém irei deixar os mais clássicos abaixo:

> 1) [HTML5 STYLE GUIDE](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp)
>
> 2) [JAVASCRIPT STYLE GUIDE](https://snowdream.github.io/javascript-style-guide/javascript-style-guide/)
>
> 3) [MÉTODOLOGIA DE ESTRUTURAÇÃO CSS (BEM)](http://getbem.com/introduction/)

Sem mais delongas, vamos a resposta da sua pergunta...

Você está **utilizando diversas bibliotecas** tome **cuidado** com isto também, um dos motivos do cuidado é porque você não tem o **total controle** **do que está ocorrendo**, **quando vai ocorrer** e **no que vai ocorrer**, **um desses exemplos é o da sua resposta**. **Preste atenção agora..**

**Você possui a seguinte estrutura HTML:**

```
    <li role="tab" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-state-default ui-tab ui-corner-left" aria-controls="tabs-11" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#tabs-11" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-1">Ensino Fundamental</a>
    </li>
```

**Observe o seguinte:**
O seu **hyperlink** `<a>` está dentro da **tag** `<li>` e a **tag** `<li>` possui as seguintes **nomenclaturas** de `.class`: `ui-tabs-tab` `ui-state-default` `ui-tab` e `ui-corner-left`. **Como não sabemos o verdadeiro funcionamento das mesmas, para que não ocorra nenhum problema o certo seria o seguinte:**

```
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a {
    color: INSIRA A COR AQUI (NOME, RGB, HEX, ENTRE OUTROS);
}
```

Pois no caso você estará modificando somente nos **tabs e navs verticais** e quando o `<li>` que está dentro deste contexto estiver com o `ui-tabs-active` irá modificar o elemento `<a>` e em mais **nenhuma outra região**.

Comment: Ual Thiago, muito bom sua explicação. Entendi perfeitamente o problema de boas práticas, vou concertar ou tentar, pois esse site quando peguei ja estava assim.

Comment: Com certeza foi muito esclarecedor, obrigado!

Comment: @MoisesFausto obrigado e agradeço! Caso puder deixar a minha resposta como a correta, agradeceria.

Comment: Esse site ai ta uma tristeza, ontem tentei melhorar algumas coisas, usando minificação de css e JS e tamanho de imagem, mas bugou o site todo. Acho que se mudar não vai ser boa ideia, seria melhor mudar alguns parametros ou refazer ele, aproveitando algumas coias.

Answer (score 2):

Tem que trocar a cor do `a` quando a `li` estiver com a classe `.ui-state-active`

```
.ui-state-active a {
    color: red;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo, isso resolveu o meu problema. Não querendo me aproveitar da suia boa vontade, mas eu fiquei sem entender o porque ela não respeitou o parametro da font, mas respeitou o do background ?

Comment: @MoisesFausto agora eu estou no celular e não da pra.inspecionar, mas acredito seja Pq o bg esta na li já o color na A. E essa com do A pode estar sendo herdada do body  ou algum outra parte do CSS por isso fiz a regra pegando o estilo da Li e do A que esta dentro dela para ser mais especifico

Comment: Isso faz sentido, realmente tinha reparado que o color na A, vinha herdado e quando eu alterava, alterava todas as outras. Você foi muito perspicaz @hugo, agradeço novamentye pela ajuda.

Comment: @MoisesFausto estamos aqui para ajudar, força nos estudos que logo vc fica fera! Abs